# Jenkins: discover branch only if specific file exists

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pipeline

Is there any Jenkins plugin to discover branches of git repository where specific file exists? Requirement I have is to run pipeline in multibranch pipeline for branches only if specific file exists. I have now:

```
            steps {
                script {
                    def config_path = 'deploy/deploy.yml'
                    if (fileExists("${config_path}") == false) {
                        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED';
                        error "Config '${config_path}' not found."
                    }
                }
            }
```

but it results in FAILED build status for commits on Bitbucket, which is false negative and I don't want that.